# Facebook Wordpress Integration - Publish action

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, facebook-opengraph

I am using the Official Facebook Plugin to Wordpress, and I am configuring the Social Publisher Settings.

Step 2 is:

> Associate an Open Graph action-object pair for your application:
>   people can publish an article

When I open OpenGraph in the Facebook page, there is no "Publish" Action available, so I clicked on the "+" sign and wrote "Publish" and selected "Article" like step 2 says.

And I get this error when I click on "Create":

> A custom Publish action is restricted. Please use the common Publish
>   action instead.

Where do I find this common Publish action?

How do I resolve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create it, they are already defined for you. Just start publishing

> Common actions do not need to be created, you can just start publishing them. They will then appear in the list of actions in your App Dashboard.

Go to your app settings after publishing and you should see it

[image: App OG Types]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/